# Minimal Api Generic CRUD with dynamic endpoint mapping

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, generics, minimal-apis

I'm trying to automate the implementation of the CRUD for my application.

I'm using the Minimal API design, and I wrote a `ICrudService<T>` which can `Get`, `Single`, `Add`, `Update` and `Delete` the `T` Entity.

Now I'm trying to automate the endpoints part. I'm able to have the `Get` and the `Single` working with this code :

```
Type[] types = 
{ 
    typeof(Place), 
    typeof(PlaceLink),
};

foreach (var type in types)
{
    var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
    var serviceType = typeof(ICrudService<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    dynamic service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(serviceType);

    app
    .MapGet($"/{type.Name.ToLower()}s", async () =>
    {
        var result = await service.Get();
        return Results.Ok(result);
    })
    .WithTags($"{type.Name}s");

    app
    .MapGet($"/{type.Name.ToLower()}s/" + "{id}", async (int id) =>
    {
        var result = await service.Single(id);
        return Results.Ok(result);
    })
    .WithTags($"{type.Name}s");
}
```

Which gives me the swagger I want :

[image]

But I'm struggling with the `Add` (and probably with the `Update` one).

Here is the actual code for the `Add` part :

```
app
.MapPost($"/{type.Name.ToLower()}s/" + "{id}", async(TYPE_OF_ENTITY entity) =>
{
    var result = await service.Add(entity);
    return Results.Ok(result);
})
.WithTags($"{type.Name}s");
```

I'm able to get the `service` by using the `.MakeGenericType(type)` function. But here, the `async(TYPE_OF_ENTITY entity)` is a signature for an anonymous function, and I don't know if there is any trick I can use to specify the `Type` of the `entity` var by using the `type` var.

The `dynamic` keyword works, but `Swagger` isn't able to know the Type of my entity, so the GUI appears raw without any default schema for the request :

how can I dynamically create the signature of my anonymous function ?

[image]

Comment: Possibly related -  [Dynamic delegate to minimal api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70571041/2501279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform dynamic Minimal API registration you can move the setup into a generic method and then call it via reflection. For example:

```cs
class MapExts
{
    public static void MapType<T>(WebApplication app)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        app
            .MapGet($"/{type.Name.ToLower()}s", async (ICrudService<T> service) =>
            {
                var result = await service.Get();
                return Results.Ok(result);
            })
            .WithTags($"{type.Name}s");

        app
            .MapGet($"/{type.Name.ToLower()}s/" + "{id}", async (int id, ICrudService<T> service) =>
            {
                var result = await service.Single(id);
                return Results.Ok(result);
            })
            .WithTags($"{type.Name}s");

        app
            .MapPost($"/{type.Name.ToLower()}s/" + "{id}", async (T entity, ICrudService<T> service) =>
            {
                var result = await service.Add(entity);
                return Results.Ok(result);
            })
            .WithTags($"{type.Name}s");
    } 
}
```

And usage:

```cs
var mapMethod = typeof(MapExts).GetMethod(nameof(MapExts.MapType));
foreach (var type in types)
{
    mapMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null, new object?[] { app });
}
```

P.S.

This:

```cs
var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
var serviceType = typeof(ICrudService<>).MakeGenericType(type);
dynamic service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
```

is bad. Not only due to using `dynamic` type (which can be opinionated claim) but this will result in the same instance of service handling all requests for the app lifetime which can lead to a lot of different issues depending on the actual service implementation.

Comment: Thanks ! It works like a charm !
I was aware of how bad the `dynamic` keyword usage was but I didn't know for the instance of the service.
Anyway, the solution you provided get ride of this issue. Thank you very much !

Comment: @M.Ozn was glad to help! _"but I didn't know for the instance of the service."_ - yes, you are creating a single instance which is captured via [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/428624/2501279) mechanism by the handler method, so yeah, it will be a single instance per lifetime.