# MapPost throws a closure error when func is from an expression

Tags: lambda, minimal-apis

I am attempting to make use of the aspnet minimal api. I am looping through classes with a specific interface and then for each method I am generating a handler for the `app.MapPost`. When I do this and run the app. If I call the API or Swagger, I get `System.InvalidOperationException: Encountered a parameter of type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure' without a name. Parameters must have a name.`

I have simplified it down to ensure that it was not the typecasting I was doing. Each version does the same, but obviously, there is something different. The desire is to be able to use `CreateHandler` in a more generic manner.

Target Framework = 7.0.

Code:

```
_ = app.MapPost("api/services/security/users/list", CreateHandler()); // Error
_ = app.MapPost("api/services/security/users/list", CreateHandler_Exp()); // Error
_ = app.MapPost("api/services/security/users/list", CreateHandler_Func()); // Works

// Error
private static Func<ListUsersArgs, IUserService, List<UserListItem>> CreateHandler_Func() {
    return (ListUsersArgs model, IUserService svc) => svc.List(model);
}

// Error
private static Func<ListUsersArgs, IUserService, List<UserListItem>> CreateHandler_Exp() {
    Expression<Func<ListUsersArgs, IUserService, List<UserListItem>>> e = (model, us) => us.List(model);
    var l = e.Compile();
    return l;
}

// Works
private static Func<ListUsersArgs, IUserService, List<UserListItem>> CreateHandler() {
    var serviceType = typeof(IUserService);
    var method = serviceType.GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "List");

    var modelObjParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ListUsersArgs), "model");
    var svcObjParam = Expression.Parameter(serviceType, "svc");

    var executeExpression = Expression.Call(svcObjParam, method.Name, null, modelObjParam);
    //var blockExpression = Expression.Block(executeExpression);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<ListUsersArgs, IUserService, List<UserListItem>>>(executeExpression, modelObjParam, svcObjParam);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

Comment: Check out this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70571041/2501279 . I was not able to overcome the issue.